# How can i join two mysql tables in a particular case

Tags: mysql, select

I have your MySql tables: "orders" and "ingredients". In "orders" I have a field where the ingredients are inserted as a string "1,2,3 ...". In the "ingredients" table I have the primary field id and another with the name of the ingredient. As the following:

[image]

Is there any way to use a SELECT to get the string of ingredients "onion, apple, kiwi ..." when i select id=1 of "orders" table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should *not* store the ingredient IDs as a comma-separated list.  As a workaround for this poor design choice, you may use MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET` function:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(i.name ORDER BY i.id) AS ingredients
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Ingredients i
    ON FIND_IN_SET(i.id, o.ingredientsid) > 0
GROUP BY
    o.id;
```

### Demo

Comment: IUnfortunately the table I have to use has been created like this and I can't modify it. Your solution works. Is there any way to have the fields that are not joined? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @FrankRosario I don't know what you want as a follow-up, but it sounds like maybe that should be another separate question.